# Writing a function for a data frame

Tags: r, function

I am a very new R user and struggling with writing a function.
I would like to write a function for the sample data frame below where the text “Number of students” is printed for each remark category with the corresponding number of students in each category.

```
student.id midterm final remark
student.1      83     81 Excellent
student.2      52    42 Work Harder
student.3      62     8 Work Harder
student.4      50    44 Work Harder
student.5      86    80 Excellent
student.6      90     1     Not Bad
student.7      73    70 Work Harder
student.8      87    84     Excellent
student.9      55    23 Work Harder
student.10      62    87     Not Bad
student.11      72    78 Work Harder
student.12      70    91     Not Bad
student.13      57    33 Work Harder
student.14      61    43 Work Harder
student.15      60    11 Work Harder
student.16      59    13 Work Harder
student.17      53    26 Work Harder
```

Comment: "I am a very new R user and struggling with writing a function ... " you would get more of a response if you detailed your struggles. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Do you need `table(df$remark)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do this. The function takes the data frame as an argument:

```
remark_frequency <- function(df){
  countTable <- as.data.frame(table(df$remark))
  for(i in 1:nrow(countTable)){
    printString <- paste("Number of students in", 
                        countTable[i,1], 
                        "category:", 
                        countTable[i,2])
    print(printString)
  }
}
```